# Finding Standard Deviation of Die

Tags: statistics

[image]

I can't figure out what to do with the given random variable, in order to find my standard deviation

Comment: Use the **definition** of standard deviation?

Comment: I have been told to use: square root of summation of x^2 * p(x) - mean^2. To find my standard deviation, but I'm confused on how to input it

Comment: Do **you** understand what the problem asks you to do?  You are specifically told to "roll a fair die n= 124 times".  Have you done **that**?  If so, how many times did it come up "0"1?  How many times did it come up "2", etc?

Answer (score 0):

The wording of the question seems a little unclear. Together with one of
the comments, I can see how your might be confused.
[I think the dice-rolling is theoretical, not intended to be done in practice.]
Here is an outline of what I think you are being asked to do.

The distribution of the number $X$ showing on one die has PDF (or PMF)
$P(X = i) = p_x(i) = 1/6,$ for $ i = 1,2,3,4,5,6.$

The definition of the sample mean is 
$$\mu = E(X) = \sum_{i=1}^6 ip(i) = \frac 16\sum_{i=1}^6 i =
 \frac 16 (1 + 2 + 3 + 4 + 5 + 6) = \frac{21}{6} = 3.5.$$

The definition of the sample variance is
$$\sigma_X^2 = \sum_{i=1}^6 (i - \mu)^2p(i) =
 \frac 16\sum_{i=1}^6 \left(i-\frac 72\right)^2
= \frac 16[(1-7/2)^2 + \cdots + (6 - 7/2)^2]  =\; ?? $$

When you get $\sigma_X^2 = Var(X),$ take the square root to get
 the required answer $\sigma_X = SD(X).$

The computation of $\sigma_X^2$ shown above is a little tedious. So the clue is that $\sigma_X^2 = E(X^2) - \mu_X^2,$ which may be a little tedious to compute because you already know $\mu_X$ from part (a).

In particular,
$$E(X^2) = \sum_{i=1}^6 i^2p(i) = \frac 16\sum_{i=1}^6 i^2 =
 \frac 16 (1^2 + 2^2 + 3^2 + 4^2 + 5^2 + 6^2) = \frac{91}{6}.$$

Now I will leave it to you to finish evaluating $\sigma_X.$

---

*Note:* In case you really were expected to roll a fair die 124 times and find
the sample mean and SD of the resulting 124 numbers, I simulated the rolling
of the die in R, with the following results:

```
x = sample(1:6, 124, repl=T)
mean(x);  sd(x)
## 3.427419    # sample mean
## 1.725813    # sample SD
table(x)
x
 1  2  3  4  5  6 
24 21 14 26 21 18   # my counts of various faces
```

Notice that my $\bar X = 3.43 \approx 3.5.$ You will find that
the sample SD of the 124 observations $S_X = 1.73 \approx \sigma_X^2,$
but results from a sample of size $n = 124$ can hardly be expected to
give you a value for $S_X$ that is equal to $\sigma_X,$ "correct to three decimals."

In 124 rolls of the die, the "expected" counts for faces 1, 2, 3, and
so on should each be around 20 or 21, but the random variation when I rolled the
die gives actual counts as low as 18 and as high as 26. This much variation from 'expected' counts is typical, not surprising. This is a random
experiment. Each time you roll the die 124 times, you will get different
results--mostly with observed counts 'pretty near' 20 or 21.